# storing images in db and map them with nhibernate

Tags: database, nhibernate

how to store images in db and map them with nhibernate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map binary data using the binary type which equates to a byte[] array in code and a varbinary in the database. This may cause performance issues if you load a number of objects containing binary data or large objects because the objects will be kept in memory in the first level cache. [This article](http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2009/03/large-object-storage-for-nhibernate-and-ddd-part-1-blobs-clobs-and-xlobs/) discusses techniques to improve performance in this situation.

Comment: Someone upvoted this today (thanks) so I thought I'd add that lazy loading a single property is coming to NHibernate: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/27/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.aspx.