# persisting byte[] to image db Field

Tags: nhibernate

I just switched to Nhibernate2.1.0.4000 with Nfluent 1.0RTM and Linq To Nhibernate 1.0.0.
since then while Calling Save some entity containing an byte[] array which is mapped to an image database field, it takes ages to finish under debugging in the VS2008 debugger.

```
public class Appendix
{
...
  public virtual byte[] appendix { get; set; }
....
}
```

If I set the byte[] array to null its  fast as aver. Also Outside VS 2008 its as fast as ever.
I cannot change the database field type from image to something else, its a legacy db.

Is there a NH pattern how to handle(map) image MSSQLdatabase fields? did something change with the new NH version?

any hint is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any changes with byte[]s in since we upgraded. How are you mapping the field?

a similiar question: [storing images in db and map them with nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808484/storing-images-in-db-and-map-them-with-nhibernate)

the article linked in the above question: http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2009/03/large-object-storage-for-nhibernate-and-ddd-part-1-blobs-clobs-and-xlobs/

Comment: I map it like
class AppendixMap : ClassMap<Appendix>
{
...
Map(x=>x.appendix);
...
}

Now the article hits the nail: I also have extreme memory consumption....